# Find() method does not find anything loaded asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, load, find

as in the answer, the .find() method does not find elements loaded asynchronously!

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="load"></span>
</div>

$( '.load' ).load( 'text.txt' );

//text.txt
<ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
//
```

In my plugin I have to find all 'li' elements but it won't work with ajax. why?

```
$.fn.plugin = function() {
var $this = this,
    $li   = $this.find( 'li' );

console.log( $li );
}

$( '#wrapper' ).plugin();
```

why? is there something wrong or it won't never work?

Answer (score 1):

Use callback  method of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` and is **asynchronous**.

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

*code*

```
$('.load').load('text.txt', function () {
    $('#wrapper').find('li');
});
```

Comment: how to do that if is a plugin to look for the loaded ajax 'li' in the page?